# Minimum deployment target for objective-zip

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, objectivezip

Can anyone tell me what is the minimum deployment target required for Objective-zip 1.0.2. They have mentioned as iOS 5.0 in their home site, but i have the deployment target set to iOS 5.1.1 and I get the error as specs found but Objective-zip 1.0.2 requires higher deployment target. 
Can anyone tell me How to support objective-zip for iOS 5.1.1 ?

Comment: Show the full error text.

Comment: Specs satisfying the `objective-zip (= 1.0.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: So it sounds like it's a dependency of objective-zip that requires > ios 5.1

Comment: Yes.. but if u check https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip , they have told at the end of the page that it supports iOS 5

Comment: I suspect that doesn't include the dependencies.  So find the dependencies and check them.

Comment: What do u mean by find dependencies ?

Comment: Determine what dependencies it uses and find what their minimum iOS target is.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how to do it as I am very new to iOS development ?

Comment: Sorry I don't use Cocoapods, so I don't know.